# java pyramid/triangle using for loop

Tags: java

i want to print a triangle/pyramid style like:

```
   1
  323
 54345
7654567
```

here is my code:

```
int lines = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i < lines; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < lines-i; j++) { 
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) { //this for loop is my problem. any solution?
            System.out.print(j);
        }

        for (int j = i; j < i+i; j++) { 
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

what i got is

```
   1
  223
 32345
4324567
```

i been studying codes while working at office and i think week long i still could not find a solution to this even i use search in Google.
i am only into enhancing my logic through conditionals and no heavy object oriented or recursion yet.

Comment: Is there an algorithm you can point us to? or a rule on how the numbers should be displayed?

From what I can gather, from top to button 1-4 then branch out incrementing by 1 in either direction on a row by row basis?

Comment: Firstly, you should use `<=` in your outer loop, so the number of lines is the same as what the variable `lines` holds.

Comment: the numbers that i got difficulty displaying are like 3 then 54 then 765 then the last loop will display the 1, 23, 345, 4567.

Comment: its like displaying an odd numbers 1, 3, 5, 7 then decreasing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your first loop is a problem you figured out in your second one! (and it has something to do with the largest number in the loop)

```
for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) { //this for loop is my problem. any solution?
    System.out.print(j);
}
```

Look at the numbers on the left of the pyramid. They start where the ones on the right end (every line of the pyramid is symmetrical). And the general formula for that number is `i + i - 1`, where `i` is the line number from your outer loop.

The second row starts at `2 * i - 1 = 2 * 2 - 1 = 3`. The third row starts at `2 * 3 - 1 = 5` etc.

Your second inner loop should therefore look like this:

```
for (int j = i + i - 1; j > i; j--) {
    System.out.print(j);
}
```

Comment: this is the solution. thanks andrei for the answer and florent for the correction :)

Comment: @RandyB. At least take a look at my solution. This one doesn't fix your spacing bug.

Comment: Are you sure there's a spacing bug? Bear in mind that @mbomb007 sets `lines` to 5 and then uses `<` instead of `<=` inside the loop, so his space computation is equivalent to your solution.

Comment: Oh... *that* explains it. Thanks.

Comment: But honestly, if he wants 4 lines, it should equal 4 for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete fixed source.

You have to start at the i-th odd number. This is `i*2-1`. And you stop at `i`. This also fixes a spacing difference introduced by changing it to `lines = 4`.

```
int lines = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {

    for (int j = 1; j < lines-i+1; j++) { 
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    for (int j = i*2-1; j > i; j--) { //this for loop is my problem. any solution?
        System.out.print(j);
    }

    for (int j = i; j < i+i; j++) { 
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Run it here: http://ideone.com/AKsc1f

Answer (score 0):

int lines = 4;

for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++) {

```
for (int j = 1; j < lines-i+1; j++) { 
    System.out.print(" ");
}
//replace this
for(int j=0; j<i-1; j++) System.out.print(i*2-j-1);
 System.out.print(i);
 for(int j=; j<i-1;j++) System.out.print(i+j+1);
//==========
System.out.println();
```

}